# Where will they meet?

Tags: geometry

A and B are running along the wall of a square park. The corners of the park are facing North, South, East and West and are named N, S, E and W respectively. They start at E and run towards S. If the speed of A is 6 times than of B, where do they meet for the 27th time?

a) between S and W
b) at S
c) between W and N
d) at N

Comment: What do they do at the park gates? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A$ runs faster, every time he meets $B$, he will have outruned him by an extra lap. Every lap measures $4$ times the length of the square, so if $x$ is the distance $B$ runs between two encounters with $A$ then:

$6x = 4+x \Rightarrow x = \frac{4}{5}$. So when they meet, $B$ would have ran $4/5$ times the side of the square.

So the $27$th time, $B$ would have run $27·\frac{4}{5} = 21 + \frac{3}{5}$ times the length of the side of the square.

Since every $4$ times, he's back on $E$, He'll be $1+\frac{3}{5}$ lenghts after $E$, i.e. between $S$ and $W$.

Comment: How are you telling that B has ran 5/6 the length of the square wherever they meet? After that I can understand the rest, its brilliant. :)

Comment: @arijitpal2009 sorry, it was ment to be $4/5$. I've edited the answer and added the explanation of why that number.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the park as a circle. We can think of the distance as degrees.

The distance A has run is 6 times longer than B's: A=6B.

When they meet, they are at the same point, but A has run significantly more degrees. Luckily, A's advantage can only consist of full rounds, so it can be said that they meet when their difference is a multiple of 360:

A-B=360k

Solving equation system (with the equation at the top): B=72k

In other words, they **meet every 72 degrees B has run**.
(Just take k=1 and you will see how that makes sense.)

The 27th time, B has run 1994 degrees, which corresponds to 5.4 rounds (you have to divide by 360).

$\frac{4}{10}$ of a round correspond to 144 degrees, and that is between S and W.

Answer (score 0):

*Another approach* : Consider the unit circle $x^2+y^2=1$ and set
$$E(1,0),S(0,1),W(-1,0),N(0,-1).$$
(Note that I set these points differently.)
Then, let $6\theta,\theta$ be the counterclockwise angle of $A, B$ respectively. 
$$6\theta-\theta=2\pi\times 27\Rightarrow \theta=10\pi+\frac{4}{5}\pi$$ tells us the answer is between $S$ and $W$.

Here, note that for the $m$-th meet, $6\theta-\theta=2\pi\times m$ holds.

Comment: How are you setting up the equation?

Comment: @arijitpal2009: For the first meet, we have $6\theta-\theta=2\pi$. If you understand this, then I'm sure you can understand that for the $m$-th meet, we have $6\theta-\theta=2\pi\times m$. Or is $6\theta=\theta+2\pi\times m$ better to understand?

Answer (score 0):

I would set it up similarly to Darth Geek, but would call $x$ the number of laps that $B$ has covered when they meet for the 27th time. $A$ will have covered $x+27$ laps, so 
$$6x=x+27,$$
and hence $x=\frac{27}5=5+\frac25$. Now noting that $\frac14<\frac25<\frac12$, we see that they will be between S and W.

Answer (score -1):

For $1$ complete round by $B$, $A$ completes 6 rounds of the square park.

[image]

Now for $B$ to meet $A$ for $27th$ time, $B$ must be completing $\frac {27} {6}$
rounds that is $4{\frac{1}{2}}$ rounds or 
$\text{starting from E towards S, he will be at a position -}\\$

$\text{$a)$ between $S$ and $W$ side of the park}\\$

Comment: I think you mean $4 + 1/2$ and not $4\times 1/2$

Comment: I am learning to write better. I can see that $\frac{27}{6}$ is same as $\frac{9}{2}$ or $4\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Wouldn't half a round get him to W?

Comment: Additionally, following your calculations, to meet for the first time, B would have to run 1/6 of a round. One can easily see that that is not the case.

Comment: that is it, $B$ is about to reach $W$, while $A$ is about to complete $27th$ round, earlier he has met 26 times, and starts towards $S$ and then $W$, before coming to $N$ and $E$  for completing 27th round.

Comment: If A and B are points, they meet *exactly* at W, not before.

Comment: I feel, they meet initially just near start point, that is before point $1$ of the total $6$ divisions, then for the second time, they meet between $E$ and $S$ that is between point $1$ and point $2$ of the 6 divisions and so on

Comment: For the second time they meet between points 2 and 3 of six divisions, but making 6 divisions isn't practical. What do you mean with reputation? How would you calculate the first time they meet?

Comment: If you dont mind me asking, how do you draw mathematical figures or  write mathematical symbols here?

Comment: @arijitpal2009 See [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/865/how-to-learn-mathjax) and [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117).